# Why do I get "Non-static method App\Models\Category::products() should not be called statically" in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot, pivot-table

Model Category.php

```
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product', 'category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Model Product.php

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category', 'category_product', 'product_id', 'category_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

HomeController.php

```
$category = Category::products()->find($id);
return view('site.category.details',[
    'details' => $category
]);
```

details.blade.php

```
@dd($details->pivot->name)
```

Comment: Because you are calling a non static method as if it were a static method. Here `Category::products()->find($id);`

Answer (score 2):

When you define a `belongsToMany` relationship, that defines the relationship, for a given Category. But by calling `Category::products()...` you haven't yet said for which category you want to get the products for.

There for you can do `$category = Category::find($category_id)` to get the category and then retrieve the products for that category by doing `$category->products`. You can of course go directly for the products like this: `Category::find($category_id)->products`.

If you call `->products` you get the result collection of products. If you call it with parentheses `->products()` then you get back the DB query class which then allows you to add more query methods such as: `->products()->where('id', $product_id)->get()`.

So I'm thinking you might have just put the `->find($id)` after the `->products()` instead of before.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, would be like this `Category::find($category_id)->products()->find($id)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load "products" on a categories you can be do it by the way:

```
$category = Category::with('products')->find($id);
```

Or another way:

```
$category = Category::find($id)->load('products');
```

You can be seen the differences between the two methods in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because `$this` is not available in a static method call and if method is not declared static, it's very possible that someone could add `$this` statement to this method not expecting that is called somewhere statically.